# BizTalk send port retry interval and retry count

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

There is one dynamic send port (Req/response) in my orchestration.
Request is sending to external system and accepting response in orch. There is a chance the external system have monthly maintenance  of 2 days. To handle that scenario

Retry interval if I set to 2 days is it impacting the performance? Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think it is a good idea, as even a transitory error of another type would then mean that message would be delayed by two days.

As maintenance is usually scheduled, either stop the send port (but don't unenlist) or stop the receive port that picks up the messages to send (preferable, especially if it is high volume), and start them again after the maintenance period.

The other option would be to build that logic into the Orchestration, that if it catches an exception that it increased the retry interval on each retry.   However as above, if it is high volume, you might be better off switching of the receive location, as otherwise you will have a high number of running instances.

Answer (score 0):

Set a service interval at the send port if you know when the receiving system will be down. If the schedule is unknown I would rather set:

- retry count = 290
- retry interval = 10 minutes
  to achieve that the messages will be transmitted over two days.